# Force.com IDE: migrate custom object from one org to another

Tags: deployment, ide, migration

I am new to Salesforce.
I created a few custom object, triggers and classes under one Saleforce entity. Later, I downloaded them all to IDE project. I want to migrate them to another Salesforce entiry. I am using "Deploy to Server" tool. I am getting the following errors in my Summary Log:

```
*** Deployment Log ***
Result: FAILED
Date: May 2, 2013 1:53:59 PM PDT

# Deployed From:
   Project name: APA Name
   Username: admin@aw13230.com
   Endpoint: www.salesforce.com

# Deployed To:
   Username: vraskin@usc.edu.devorg2
   Endpoint: cs15.salesforce.com

# Deploy Results:
   File Name:    objects/Authors__c.object
   Full Name:  Authors__c.APA_author_name__c
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: Entity Authors__c not found

   File Name:    objects/Authors__c.object
   Full Name:  Authors__c.First_Name__c
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: Entity Authors__c not found

   File Name:    objects/Authors__c.object
   Full Name:  Authors__c.Middle_Name__c
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: Entity Authors__c not found

   File Name:    objects/Authors__c.object
   Full Name:  Authors__c.All
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: Entity 'Authors__c' not found.

   File Name:    package.xml
   Full Name:  package.xml
   Action:  UPDATED
   Result:  SUCCESS
   Problem: n/a

# Test Results:
   n/a
```

This object does not exist on a second entity.
Can anyone tell me why it is failing to deploy it ?

Thanks.

*** EDIT 1 - package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <members>AccountContactRole</members>
        <members>Activity</members>
        <members>Asset</members>
        <members>Campaign</members>
        <members>CampaignMember</members>
        <members>Case</members>
        <members>CaseContactRole</members>
        <members>Contact</members>
        <members>ContentVersion</members>
        <members>Contract</members>
        <members>ContractContactRole</members>
        <members>Event</members>
        <members>Idea</members>
        <members>Lead</members>
        <members>Opportunity</members>
        <members>OpportunityCompetitor</members>
        <members>OpportunityContactRole</members>
        <members>OpportunityLineItem</members>
        <members>PartnerRole</members>
        <members>PersonAccount</members>
        <members>Product2</members>
        <members>Site</members>
        <members>Solution</members>
        <members>Task</members>
        <members>User</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>27.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: are you deploying to a production instance where tests are failing?

Comment: Can you post the content of your package.xml? If it's long - especially the nodes close to `<name>CustomObject</name>` - does it contain a `<members>*</members>` or `<members>Authors__c</members>`? I fail to understand how deployment of object's file can complain that said object is not visible :/

Comment: @greenstork - it says endpoint is cs15 (sandbox) and no tests were run :) It dies on initial validation.

Comment: and that's what I get for not reading closely, noted

Comment: @greenstork It is our development sandbox env.

Comment: @eyescream I just posted my package.xml file. Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't your custom objects in the package file? Try resetting your "project contents" to include all and re-deploying. I avoid using Eclipse for deployments because of inconsistent behaviour I see sometimes surrounding the management of package.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I thought - your package.xml is incomplete :)

When you were fetching components from server you probably ticked only "objects - standard". You can either quickly edit your xml manually or go to "Add/Remove metadata components" and select "objects - custom". Will be much faster to just edit!

[image]

Make sure that relevant part of package.xml looks like that:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <members>Account</members>
    <members>AccountContactRole</members>

    (skipped some nodes... All you really need is to add this 1st one)

    <members>User</members>
    <members>UserLicense</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

Then right - click the `src/objects` directory and go "Force.com -> Refresh from server".

Some new files should pop up in the directory, `Authors__c.object` being one of them (or if there was one already - it should get more content inside). Try the deployment now?

Comment: I thought I downloaded both types. I will try to edit this next week at work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've sometimes seen this when the object doesn't exist already in the target org, though I've never narrowed down what the problem specifically is.

Create an empty custom object with the same name in the target org (`Authors__c`) and then try the deploy, should work.